# How to count the number of subscribers in a facebook group with python?

Tags: python, facebook, parsing

I tried the `requests` and `beautifulsoup` libraries, but apparently the number of subscribers appears as a result of js execution. The `selenium` library could help, but I'm having trouble running this library on heroku. The facebook api also failed to do this, because I did not find how to get the id of a group that I am not the owner of. What is the easiest way for this purpose?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape. So you have to use the API.

Comment: But how do I get the id of a group that I am not the owner of? I haven't found any ways

Comment: Then why would that info be your business to begin with?